# How to prove $\sum_n e^{ik n}$ is a periodic sum of delta functions?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, dirac-delta

I want to show that $\sum_n e^{ik n}$ is an infinite periodic sum of delta functions, where $n$ were integers from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

I tried to manipulate the expression $\delta(x-a)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ip(x-a)dp}$ but without any luck.

Comment: Do you mean to compute that sum? It’s true that in some sense it equals a delta function.

Comment: Ah, this is not trivial. Yes, that sum converges "weakly", and, a stronger assertion, in a Sobolev space. The formulaic assertion is a distributional form of the Poisson Summation Formula... is this a context that makes sense to you?

Comment: @Funktorality It wasn't only one delta function. I plotted the sum, and it was an infinite sum of periodic delta function $\sum_n e^{ikn} = \sum_n \delta (k- n/L)$ where the $L$ were some period.

Comment: We’re both right. I was thinking about it as a Fourier series, so on the torus it is only a single delta function ;)

Comment: @paulgarrett Thank you so much! I googled Poisson Summation Formula and the wiki lead to Dirac comb, it listed a proof of how to obtain from expand $\sum_k\delta(t-kT)$ in Fourier space. But suppose that I don't know the form of the function(don't know that it's a delta function), is there anyway to expand $\sum_n e^{ikn}$ directly? Also, what did you mean by sum converges "weakly", did you mean that it must be an infinite sum?

Comment: This [boils down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel#Relation_to_the_delta_function) to the Dirichlet kernel.

Comment: I think there is no way to understand that sum "directly", since it does require effort (of some sort) to prove the Poisson summation formula... The sense of "weak" convergence is in (for example) the "weak dual/star topology" on the space of (tempered?) distributions.

Comment: [This is related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3723896/verify-that-the-fourier-transform-of-impulse-train-is-another-impulse-train/3723908#3723908).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To give you an idea of why it is true, recall Fourier series. Given a nice enough $2\pi$-periodic function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ we can write $f(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} c_n e^{inx}$ where $c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x) \, e^{-inx} \, dx$. Now take $f(x) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} 2\pi \, \delta(x-k)$, the $2\pi$-period extension of $\delta(x)$. Then $c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} 2\pi\,\delta(x) \, e^{-inx} \, dx = 1$ and we get
$f(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{inx}.$

Comment: (+1)  All too easy.  [This is related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3723896/verify-that-the-fourier-transform-of-impulse-train-is-another-impulse-train/3723908#3723908).